# How to build the equation for this question?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a class, there are $20$ people. In this class, there are $4$ people who know only english, $9$ who don't know french, $7$ who don't know english. Then, how many people who know both language are there?

Here is my venn diagram

[image: venn diagram]

$$r(1) = \text {who know english}$$
$$r(3) = \text {who know french}$$
$$r(2) = \text {who know both}$$
$$r(4) = \text {who know no language}$$

I'm building the equation now

$$\sum_{i = 1} r(i) = 20$$
$$r(1) + r(2) + r(3) + r(4) = 20$$
$$r(1) = 4$$

I don't have any idea about how to find $r(2)$. What is the correct equation we ought to use?

Comment: Let E be the number who speak English.  F be the number who speak French.  Then 20 - E = 4, 20 - F = 9.  The r notation is too clumbsy to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that there are $9$ people who don't know French means that there are $9$ people outside the $F$ circle, meaning that:

$$r(1)+r(4)=9$$

Likewise, the fact that there are $7$ people who don't know English means that there are $9$ people outside the $E$ circle, meaning that:

$$r(3)+r(4)=7$$

I assume you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

$r(1)+r(4)=9;\;r(3)+r(4)=7$

$r(1) + r(2) + r(3) + r(4) = 20$

$r(1)=4$

$r(4)=5$

$r(3)=2$

$r(2)=9$

[image]